# Hanging unframed stained glass-type panels

Tags: glass

I have two stained glass panels that are literally just glass all along the edges.  They are roughly about three feet by about a foot each.  I think they were panels in a piece of furniture originally.  I scored them at a garage sale for like 10 bucks - so I couldn't pass them up.

Anyway - I would love to hang them in my bay window - in the two middle bay window panels that do not open.

My question is - how do I do this?  I am not a glass-maker so am not going to try to drill holes in the glass.  I also do not solder so I am not looking to make a frame and hooks that way.  I would in fact simply lean them against the window - but they are a few inches short and would lean on the actual windows themselves.  Plus I have two cats so I need them secure.

I am open to almost anything that does not require a huge expense and/or weird specialty tools.

Answer (score 2):

The glass bits around the edge are not fully encapsulated without a frame. This is a risk -- damage and / or injury.  I would recommend taking them to a picture-framing business and seeing if you can't get a reasonably cheap metal frame cut to size.  Obviously you wouldn't need a matte :-), but you might want some extra pads/shims to keep the stained glass panels from rattling in the frame.

Comment: Or a wood frame, but in any case, a frame of some sort is the solution here.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. :) 

What do you think about a cable hanging system?  Maybe I could attach to the top and bottom of the window bay very close to the windows.  I found this so far - but wouldn't trust this particular system with actual glass...  http://mediafinishings.com/hanging_solutions/cable_hanging_system/#! 

If not, I guess framing them would be the only way to go...